# TOTP password reuse clarification

Tags: totp

If a TOTP is 6 digits (the most common length), that means there are 999,999 possible 6 digit numerical values.
So if it's supposed to be a one time password then that means that a OTP cannot be reused.
So that means a user would only be able to login a maximum of 999,999 times since at one point all OTP's will be used. Then what happens, they can't login anymore ? Am I missing something here ?

Trying to figure out if my thinking is wrong.

Comment: Not `999,999` possible values, but `1,000,000` possible values because `000000` is a valid 6-digit string.

Comment: _"So if it's supposed to be a one time password then that means that a OTP cannot be reused. "_ - **No**. That's not how TOTP works.

Comment: OTP = one time password - so if a OTP is say 234 567, then we shouldn't be able to re-use that OTP ever. I know I am missing something here but one time password is well one time and should not ever be re-used (literally that is)

Comment: "(T)OTP" does not mean _literally_ "one time" password. In this context "one time" means "unpredictable" (from an attacker's PoV). There is no expectation that a TOTP code won't ever re-appear at some point in the future: what matters is that whatever the next code is, is unpredictable without knowing the initial seed value of the PRNG used.

Comment: Every thing I read says that you have to validate if the TOTP has already been used and refuse it if so. So if the TOTP can repeat, how can you validate this ?

Comment: Where in the HOTP/TOTP RFCs are you reading that?

Comment: From the RFC : 
"The verifier MUST NOT accept
   the second attempt of the OTP after the successful validation has
   been issued for the first OTP, which ensures one-time only use of an
   OTP."

Comment: Read the sentence that preceding that one you quoted: "a prover may send the same OTP inside a given time-step window multiple times to a verifier.  The verifier MUST NOT accept the second attempt of the OTP after the successful validation has been issued for the first OTP" - the context is about reuse in the same time-step: not potential re-generation of the same hashed PRNG value in a second time-step.

Comment: So the OTP validation for preventing re-use is based on the time step where the OTP occurred in ? So in the database for the user I would have to store the time step window matched after a successful validation and check on next validation if the totp is in the time step window stored in the database for the user ?

Comment: What I'm doing is when the user successfully logs in, I store the one-time code used for that login.  When verifying the OTP, compare to the db entry and reject if it matches.  This should work fine except in the extremely rare (if ever) instance that the same code is randomly generated twice in a row (which, honestly, the software should simply not allow anyway).

Comment: My method would also fail in the extremely unlikely case that somebody logs in, and at some later date it just happens to generate the exact same OTP code.  So... literally one in a million chance that you can't log in legitimately for (max) 30 seconds.  Doesn't have to be twice in a row, but two logins in a row, regardless of when they happen. Fixable by also storing timestamp of last login -- which I do anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a [one-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) of any sort, it's a challenge response system implicitly based on time which is why those codes expire quickly. They're only valid within a narrow window of time.

The numbers will repeat, they're effectively random, but the odds of getting a repeat are quite low if you use TOTP only a handful of times a day.

Comment: No-one said anything about one-time-pads.

Comment: @Dai I'm including that as an example of single-use codes.

Comment: So if the OTP can and will repeat, then it's technically not "one time"

Comment: I think the idea is you use them once when logging in, not that that particular code is used once and once only.

Comment: The point is this: I'm a hacker and somehow I can see your keystrokes. You enter username and password.  I've got them. You enter TOTP code. I've got that. I immediately try to use them to log in.  Foiled!  Even though I'm within the 30 second window for that code, it doesn't work for me, specifically because you already used it.